# kill & wait in one step

Tags: linux, bash, kill, waitpid

If I use a combination to kill a child process in batch and wait for it's termination, I use

```
kill $PID
wait $PID
```

If the process exists immediately, the `wait` will fail, since the pid is not running anymore.

Is there a way to combine both statements to a single one to aviod the error?

Edit: The process I have to kill uses a tempfile; thus it has to be closed (and not just signaled to close) to start it again. Checking the return value of `kill` does not help, since this indicates whether the signal was delivered successfully.

Comment: What is the purpose of your `wait`? What do you really want to do?

Comment: You know that `kill` already returns a code that you can check to see if it was successful, right? ;-) If you want to kill the process no matter what, you can try `kill -9 $PID`.

Comment: If you want to execute commands sequentially it is a good idea to check out [$$ ; || etc.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Lists)

Otherwise, maybe a while loop can help you out.

`while [ $(kill ${PID}) ]; do "nothing" ;done`

Comment: @SigveKarolius Wrong. `kill $PID` returns immediately regardless of whether the job is actually killed or not. Just write a simply script that traps and ignores `SIGINT`, and see how `kill` works (it will return `0`, although the job is not killed).

Comment: Then I'm afraid you need to find something else... Why not use some polling to *wait* until some event (as the creation of a file named `closeDone` make by the process)? Or make the process sleep for a while before exiting? Make the script sleep for a while after killing? Note that the latests are almost *tricky*. Do you have control over the source code of the process?

Comment: Regarding what you want to do: why don't you use a unique tempfile each time? (Check out `mktemp`.)

Comment: Also, a not-so-safe way is to simply check whether the PID still exists.

Comment: Sorry about my ignorance of how kill works. Let me try some more ignorance: maybe you can use `ps` to check the status of the process after using `kill`?

Comment: You can use `while kill $PID 2>/dev/null; do sleep 0.01; done`. After PID exits, kill will fail & loop will break. There is a possibility of race condition though - another process may start in that 0.01 second, which can possibly have same PID...

Comment: @4ae1e1: Because the binary I have to kill can not be changed.

Comment: @SigveKarolius: I don't want to do this, because the pid might be used again in the meantime by another process. Then, it'd be better to use wait, since this guarantees that the process is at least a child process.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not a one-liner, but would you be willing to consider spawning off the kill with a short sleep, then waiting in the main thread? Something like:

```
(sleep 1; kill $PID) &
wait $PID
```

This addresses your concern of the PID being reused after the kill. Even if you reduce the `sleep` to something much smaller, it introduces idle time, but it should at least ensure that you `wait` on the correct process.

Comment: Not as elegant as I hoped, but an interesting idea!

Answer (score 2):

Effectively, there is not an atomic kill and wait since they are two separate system calls.  Some wrapper must be written to execute both functions.

If you do not care about the status,

```
kill $PID 2> /dev/null
wait $PID 2> /dev/null
```

If you do care about the status, but do not want an error message, do something like

```
if ! kill $PID 2> /dev/null; then
    # Error logic here
fi
```

The fancy way for both is a function

```
killAndWait() {
    kill $1 2> /dev/null && wait $1 2> /dev/null
}
```

Then, do

```
killAndWait $PID
```

Comment: They may be two separate syscalls, but at the syscall level, `wait()` is a valid and expected thing to do on a process that you've just killed. I can't speak to what `kill` and `wait`'s semantics are in Bash, though.

Answer (score 0):

> ```sh
> kill $PID
> wait $PID
> ```
>
> If the process exists immediately, the `wait` will fail, since the pid is not running anymore.

**As long as `$PID` really points to a child process of the shell,** I don't think `wait` *will* fail. I don't see an error with your code.

Experiment:

```
bash-3.2$ while : ; do ls > /dev/null ; done &
[1] 44908
bash-3.2$ kill 44908
[1]+  Terminated: [...]
bash-3.2$ wait 44908
bash-3.2$ echo $?
143
```

143 is the return code for SIGTERM, so the `kill` worked as expected, and Bash could `wait` for the dead process.